# check if a raster is flipped

Tags: r, raster, rgdal

I have a raster with the following properties

```
  gdalinfo <- try (rgdal::GDALinfo(rasterFile))
  
  # Warning message:
  #  In rgdal::GDALinfo(rasterFile) : statistics not supported by this driver
  
  gdalinfo
  rows        36 
  columns     64 
  bands       1 
  lower left origin.x        91.17 
  lower left origin.y        -14.73 
  res.x       1 
  res.y       1 
  ysign       -1 
  oblique.x   0 
  oblique.y   0 
  driver      GTiff 
  projection  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
  file        C:/earthengine/historical/raw/tmax_1987_ACCESS1-0__0.tif 
  apparent band summary:
    GDType hasNoDataValue NoDataValue blockSize1 blockSize2
  1 Float32          FALSE           0         32         64
  apparent band statistics:
    Bmin       Bmax Bmean Bsd
  1 -4294967295 4294967295    NA  NA
  Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
```

I suspect that this raster is reversed so I flip it

```
  my_ras_cel <- raster(rasterFile)
  
  # reverse it
  my_ras_cel_rev <- flip(my_ras_cel, direction='y')
```

Plotting the two rasters together

```
  ras_stack <- stack(my_ras_cel, my_ras_cel_rev)
  
  spplot(ras_stack)
```

[image]

I can make out that the flipped (lower panel) is the right raster since it follows
the land mass that I am interested in (malaysia, Indonesia)

My question is there any way I can check if my raster are indeed flipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GDALinfo output   `ysign       -1`
suggests that the data are not flipped. That is all the info the file has about this.

But the data clearly are flipped, for the reason you give, and the file is wrong in this regard.

Comment: Thank you. I was processing this data from googleearth engine via R and downloading locally. Not sure where it went wrong since even if ysign is -1, my data is still flipped. I need to check why this is happening. thanks